# ICMP reply packets not received by original pinger via gateway

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have been unable to get ICMP response packet to come back to the original pinger.

Right now I have the following tcpdump on the VPN server (which is the gateway as well):

```
## VPN server (10.131.102.12, 10.10.0.1)
02:22:38.897538 IP 10.131.102.32 > 10.10.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 7093, seq 444, length 64
02:22:38.913673 IP 10.10.0.2 > 10.131.102.32: ICMP echo reply, id 7093, seq 444, length 64
```

The VPN client also has both request and reply:

```
## VPN client (10.10.0.2)
10:26:05.255495 IP 10.10.0.1 > 10.10.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 7198, seq 97, length 64
10:26:05.255567 IP 10.10.0.2 > 10.10.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 7198, seq 97, length 64
```

But on the LAN device, it never received the echo reply:

```
## LAN device (10.131.102.32)
02:24:29.964862 IP 10.131.102.32 > 10.10.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 7198, seq 4, length 64
```

Here's the iptables that I ran on the VPN server:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I enabled IP forwarding on the VPN server.

Does anyone know what's going on? I tried many things but none seems to have helped. Weird thing is that the VPN server and client can ping the LAN device and get response back. I tried disabling rp_filter too but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found out that the server had firewall protection for foreign source IP address and had it disabled which fixed the issue. It was not visible on the control panel so I had to use API call to do it.